# How to create an array of arrays using numpy.append or numpy.concatenate

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array, append, concatenation

How can I create and array of arrays from individual arrays?

input:

```
print(shingle_set1)
print(shingle_set2)
```

output:

```
[12 14] 
[11 16]
```

input:

```
total_shingle_set = numpy.append(shingle_set1, shingl_set2)
total_shingle_set = numpy.concatenate((shingle_set1, shingle_set2))
```

output for both statements:

```
[12 14 11 16]
```

The output above is one long array, which I don't want. I want to preserve each array in an array of arrays, like the following output:

```
[[12 14] [11 16]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Experimented a bit more and the following gave me the answer:

```
total_shingle_set = numpy.concatenate(([shingle_set1], [shingle_set2]))
```

output:

```
[[12 14] [11 16]]
```